# Associating an X509Certificate2 certificate with a private key in .NET

Tags: c#, x509certificate

I'm trying to create an X509Certificate2 object by using this code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9250034/5589417

How can I get the private key that corresponds to the certificate's public key?

I have these methods for encryption and decryption:

```
    public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] plainBytes, X509Certificate2 cert)
    {
        RSACryptoServiceProvider publicKey = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PublicKey.Key;
        byte[] encryptedBytes = publicKey.Encrypt(plainBytes, false);
        return encryptedBytes;
    }

    public static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] encryptedBytes, X509Certificate2 cert)
    {
        RSACryptoServiceProvider privateKey = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;
        byte[] decryptedBytes = privateKey.Decrypt(encryptedBytes, false);
        return decryptedBytes;
    }
```

When I use the Decrypt method I get a NullRefereneceException for privateKey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to setup manually `PrivateKey` property for certificate instance. I also updated code from old answer you linked and removed using of obsolete methods:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var cert = GenerateCertificate("localhost");

    byte[] ciphertext = Encrypt(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello world!"), cert);
    byte[] plaintext = Decrypt(ciphertext, cert);

    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(plaintext));
}

static X509Certificate2 GenerateCertificate(string certName)
{
    var secureRandom = new SecureRandom(new CryptoApiRandomGenerator());
    var keypairgen = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
    // RSA key size = 1024 bits
    keypairgen.Init(new KeyGenerationParameters(secureRandom, 1024));

    var keypair = keypairgen.GenerateKeyPair();

    var gen = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();
    // we will use SHA256 signature
    var signatureFactory = new Asn1SignatureFactory("SHA256WITHRSA", keypair.Private, secureRandom);

    var CN = new X509Name("CN=" + certName);
    var SN = BigInteger.ProbablePrime(120, new Random());

    gen.SetSerialNumber(SN);
    gen.SetSubjectDN(CN);
    gen.SetIssuerDN(CN);
    gen.SetNotAfter(DateTime.MaxValue);
    gen.SetNotBefore(DateTime.Now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0, 0)));
    gen.SetPublicKey(keypair.Public);

    var newCert = gen.Generate(signatureFactory);

    var x509cert = new X509Certificate2(DotNetUtilities.ToX509Certificate(newCert));
    var rsa = RSA.Create();
    var publicKey = (RsaKeyParameters)keypair.Public;
    var privateKey = (RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)keypair.Private;
    var parameters = new RSAParameters
    {
        Modulus = publicKey.Modulus.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
        Exponent = publicKey.Exponent.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),

        P = privateKey.P.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
        Q = privateKey.Q.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
        DP = privateKey.DP.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
        DQ = privateKey.DQ.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
        InverseQ = privateKey.QInv.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
        D = privateKey.Exponent.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
    };
    rsa.ImportParameters(parameters);
    // at this point X509Certificate2 will check if PrivateKey matches PublicKey
    x509cert.PrivateKey = rsa;

    return x509cert;
}

public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] plainBytes, X509Certificate2 cert)
{
    RSACryptoServiceProvider publicKey = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PublicKey.Key;
    byte[] encryptedBytes = publicKey.Encrypt(plainBytes, false);
    return encryptedBytes;
}

public static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] encryptedBytes, X509Certificate2 cert)
{
    RSACryptoServiceProvider privateKey = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;
    byte[] decryptedBytes = privateKey.Decrypt(encryptedBytes, false);
    return decryptedBytes;
}
```